# what's meaning of orphans in django's paginator?

Tags: python, django, pagination

I found the /django/core/paginator.py source code:

```
class Paginator(object):
def __init__(self, object_list, per_page, orphans=0, allow_empty_first_page=True):
    self.object_list = object_list
    self.per_page = int(per_page)
    self.orphans = int(orphans)
    self.allow_empty_first_page = allow_empty_first_page
    self._num_pages = self._count = None
```

what's the attribute **orphans** meaning?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/#django.core.paginator.Paginator)

> orphans
>     The minimum number of items allowed on the last page, defaults
>     to zero. Use this when you don’t want to have a last page with very
>     few items. If the last page would normally have a number of items less
>     than or equal to orphans, then those items will be added to the
>     previous page (which becomes the last page) instead of leaving the
>     items on a page by themselves. For example, with 23 items,
>     per_page=10, and orphans=3, there will be two pages; the first page
>     with 10 items and the second (and last) page with 13 items.